# Android Navigationdrawer with swipe tabs

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs, navigation-drawer

I am having trouble implementing both Navigation drawer and swipe tabs.
When I use navigation drawer and I click on some items a new fragment replaces a FrameView (called content_frame) in my project. The problem became apparent when I implemented swipe tabs using PageAdapter. Now when I click on navigation drawer and a new Fragment is commited into content_frame it overlaps with current Tab.
It's because I use content_frame to replace fragments from Navigation drawer and use pageadapter to create 3 fixed tabs. Is there a way to make it so for example a fragment would replace current tab or tabs would just dynamically load into a FrameLayout like my content_frame? It would help with further development as well.

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.pawel.zpi.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:theme="@style/NavigationViewStyle"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.pawel.zpi.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#2A2A29"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            android:background="#2A2A29"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.teatr.zpi.dev;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.teatr.zpi.dev.adapters.ViewPagerAdapter;
import com.teatr.zpi.dev.fragments.MainFragment;
import com.teatr.zpi.dev.fragments.Najnowsze;
import com.teatr.zpi.dev.fragments.SpektakleActivity;
import com.teatr.zpi.dev.fragments.Ulubione;
import com.teatr.zpi.dev.fragments.Wszystkie;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    NavigationView navigationView;
    DrawerLayout drawer;
    FragmentManager fm;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    TabLayout tabLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.logo_capitol);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        fm = getFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.viewpager, new MainFragment()).commit();

    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Najnowsze(), "Najnowsze");
        adapter.addFragment(new Wszystkie(), "Wszystkie");
        adapter.addFragment(new Ulubione(), "Ulubione");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }



    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        fm = getFragmentManager();

        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id){
            case R.id.nav_spektakle:
                fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new SpektakleActivity()).commit();
            break;
            case R.id.nav_ulubione:
                break;
            case R.id.nav_jezyki:
                if(!navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_jezyki_polski).isVisible()){
                    navigationView.getMenu().setGroupVisible(R.id.nav_jezyki_group, true);
                }else{
                    navigationView.getMenu().setGroupVisible(R.id.nav_jezyki_group, false);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.nav_jezyki_polski:
                navigationView.getMenu().setGroupVisible(R.id.nav_jezyki_group, false);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_jezyki_english:
                navigationView.getMenu().setGroupVisible(R.id.nav_jezyki_group, false);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_jezyki_deutsch:
                navigationView.getMenu().setGroupVisible(R.id.nav_jezyki_group, false);
                break;

            case R.id.nav_info_teatr:
                break;
            case R.id.nav_info_app:
                break;
            case R.id.nav_kontakt:
                break;
        }



        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

ViewPagerAdapter.java

```
    package com.teatr.zpi.dev.adapters;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Pawel on 19.03.2016.
 */
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```